# cannot change the width of html

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and this is the assignment that I am working on. When I set the width of the green box to be 50% or 30px, the width of it does not change. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
.topcorner {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7Lhmzj91/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Change the width of the Item 1 at content in your css

```
#content {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #90EE90; /* green */
}
```

**Solution 2**

Remove the width property from content

```
#content {
  background-color: #90EE90; /* green */
}
```

Read more about Selectors [here](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/using_selectors/)